# How to find out which type of user is accessing action method code in controller - mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am not sure how to put this question or where to ask it, lets say i have a cms, which has three types of users, a retailer, manufacturer and a customer support (this guy can access all the information that a retailer and manufacturer can access). Now let say there is a products controller that has an action method called "view products list". Now a retailer can only view products on his website and so can a manufacturer, but a customer support can view a list of manufacturers and retailers and choose on which one's products s/he wants to view. Lets say all this code is in the same action method "view products list". Now is this a good practice ? To have all the code for all three types of users in the same action method ? Second how do i figure out which code should (if condition) should run inside the action method based on the user type assuming that i am using mvc built in login system and roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) It's fine to have this in one action method, you don't want to be creating new action methods if new roles are added.

(2) You can use e.g.

```
If User.IsInRole("CustomerSupport") { ... }
```

You might also want to consider locking down the action method so that only roles catered for inside the method are allowed access.  Use the [Authorize] attribute to accomplish that.  E.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Retailer, Manufacturer, CustomerSupport")]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is fine if you have the same action for all three types of users. There are several ways to achieve what you want. Please take a look at dependency injection for example. You want your repository method (responsible for bringing up data) to be different for each type (you can use factory pattern to generate different repository classes for different types of users and then inject it to the class which fetches data).

Answer (score 0):

Your actions are your access points. You shouldn't have a different action for each role. What happens if you have 30 roles? You'll have 30 actions?

Once again, controller is only your access point, so user navigates to a URL, he gets routed to the right action method, then the method should direct user to the right business logic. It's your business logic that needs to figure out whether they are permitted to do the action or not. MVC is only your presentation, so what are the chances that you will have to use a different presentation layer in a near future?